# How to save new Node into loaded XML from FTP server using PHP

Tags: php, xml, ftp

I load myfile.xml from FTP server (`simplexml_load_file` see PHP below). Now I want to add a new node and save this new node in the loaded xml (myfile.xml) file from the FTP server.

myfile.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<News>
    <NewsModel>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Headline>my First</Headline>
        <ShortDescription></ShortDescription>
        <Description></Description>
        <LinkText></LinkText>
        <Link></Link>
    </NewsModel>
    <NewsModel>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <Headline>my second</Headline>
        <ShortDescription></ShortDescription>
        <Description></Description>
        <LinkText></LinkText>
        <Link></Link>
    </NewsModel>
</News>
```

My PHP code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $msg = '';
    if (isset($_POST['btnSpeichern']) && !empty($_POST['inputHeadline']) && !empty($_POST['inputShorDesc']) && !empty($_POST['inputDesc'])) {
    
        $ftp_server = "myhost";
        $ftp_username = "myuser";
        $ftp_pass = "mypassword";
        $server_file = "myfile.xml";
        $xmlurl = "ftp://$ftp_username:$ftp_pass%21@$ftp_server/$server_file";
    
        $xml=simplexml_load_file($xmlurl)or die("Kann keine Verbindung zu $xmlurl aufbauen");
        
        $entry = $xml->addChild('NewsModel');
        $entry->addChild('ID',$_POST['inputIDNumber']);
        $entry->addChild('Headline',$_POST['inputHeadline']);
        $entry->addChild('ShortDescription',$_POST['inputShorDesc']);
        $entry->addChild('Description',$_POST['inputDesc']);
        $entry->addChild('LinkText',$_POST['inputLinkText']);
        $entry->addChild('Link',$_POST['inputLink']);
        
        $xml->addChild($entry);
    
        $xml->asXML($server_file);  
    }
?>
```

The file gets loaded correctly (I see the two Nodes) from the FTP server. I can add the new Node to the existing Nodes, but the file is saved as new file. In the new file all three nodes are visible.

What I want is, to load the file from the FTP server, add a new node and save it to the loaded file, not to a new one.

If this is not possible, how can I move the new created file to the FTP server and delete the existing one?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save the file to the FTP server, use full URL (`$xmlurl`)  in the `asXML`:

```
$xml->asXML($xmlurl);
```

I do not understand why that is not working for you.

---

Alternatively, you can save the XML to a string and use native PHP FTP functionality, like [FTP URL wrapper](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ftp.php) with `file_put_contents`:

```
$context = stream_context_create(['ftp' => ['overwrite' => true]];
$s = $xml->asXML()
file_put_contents($xmlurl, $s, 0, $context);
```